# How to fix a function to manage Matrix?

Tags: function, matrix, header-files

i am working with header files for the first time but also have a problem understanding one code.

Here i need to define `int setze_element(int zeile, int spalte, double wert)` function in a header file that i want to use in mine **cpp main File**, only i can't figure it out how i could do that.

I wrote a code below where i would think that i would be able to write my data into a matrix, only i can't figure it out in what variable i should save it. I assumed in one of the Object at a public section.

I would really appreciate for some hints.

**HEADER FILE**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{

public:

    Matrix();
    Matrix(int zeilen, int spalten);
    Matrix(const Matrix& m);                  // Copy-Konstruktór
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix operator = (const Matrix& m);    // Zuweisungsoperator

    
    int setze_element(int zeile, int spalte, double wert)
    {

        int flag = 1;

        if (flag == 1)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < zeile; z++)
            { 
                for (int s = 0; s < spalte; s++)
                {
                    operator [z][s] = wert;
                    int flag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flag = 0;
            cout << "Zeile und Spalte liegt ausserhalb des gültigen Bereichs!" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

**CPP FILE**

```
    #include "matrix.h"
    #include <iostream>
    
    
    using namespace std;
    
    
    void belegen_m1(Matrix& m)
    {
        double cmat[5][3] = { { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                              { 0.0, 2.0, 0.0 },
                              { 0.0, 0.0, 3.0 },
                              { 4.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                              { 0.0, 5.0, 0.0 }
        };
        for (int z = 0; z < m.zeilen(); z++)
            for (int s = 0; s < m.spalten(); s++)
                if (m.setze_element(z, s, cmat[z][s]) == 0)
                {
                    cout << "Fehler bei belegen_m1(), Abbruch" << endl;
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
    
    
    }


int main()
{
    Matrix m1(5, 3);


    belegen_m1(m1);

    cout << "m1:" << endl << m1 << endl;
```